# Where do I save a downloaded package?

Tags: glossaries

I have been working with LaTeX for a while, but found that my glossary package is the incorrect version since it give undefined sequences. I've downloaded the package 4.18 2015-09-09, but where do I save it and how do I unpackage it to take effect?

Comment: Better use the package manager of your TeX distribution. Doing stuff manually leads to faults quite often.